# MySQL ranking a column with ties

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a Scores table with the following schema

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 3.50  |
| 2  | 3.65  |
| 3  | 4.00  |
| 4  | 3.85  |
| 5  | 4.00  |
| 6  | 3.65  |
+----+-------+
```

I've tried the following:

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;
SELECT Id, Score, CASE
    WHEN @prev_value = Score THEN @rank_count
    WHEN @prev_value := Score THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
END AS Rank
FROM Scores
ORDER BY Score
```

In order to get

```
+-------+------+
| Score | Rank |
+-------+------+
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 4.00  | 1    |
| 3.85  | 2    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.65  | 3    |
| 3.50  | 4    |
+-------+------+
```

But instead I get this error:

```
Line 3: SyntaxError: near 'SET @rank_count = 0;
SELECT Id, Score, CASE
    WHEN @prev_value := Score THEN @'
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: `Rank` is not a good name for a column because since MySQL 8.0 it is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Assignment, "`WHEN @prev_value := Score THEN`", vs comparison, "`WHEN @prev_value = Score THEN`". I'd go with one of the suggestions from the answers however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count all the **distinct scores** that are greater than each row's score and add 1 to the result:

```
select 
  s.score,
  ((select count(distinct score) from scores where score > s.score) + 1) rank
from scores s
order by s.score desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcN4aYMLTvXWqbv4KknjLG/1)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `DENSE_RANK()` function, as in:

```
select 
  Score,
  dense_rank() over(order by Score desc) as Rank
from Scores
order by Score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables.  I think you just need a single query:

```
SELECT Id, Score,
       (CASE WHEN @prev_value = Score THEN @rank_count
             WHEN @prev_value := Score THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
        END) AS Rank
FROM (SELECT s.*
      FROM Scores s
      ORDER BY Score s
     ) s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 0) params;
```

More recent versions of MySQL require the ordering in a subquery.  Of course, the most recent versions offer `DENSE_RANK()` which is preferable.